# My Jar Files Won't Open, and My Motivation to Solve the Issue is Dying

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, jar-signing

Sorry for the crappy title.

I've been building games in Java since February, teaching myself as I go along. Recently, I worked on a dungeon crawler for over a month using Java FX, and I was quite pleased with the result. I was, in fact, so pleased with the game that I decided to publish it on my Game Jolt account, which I had previously used to produce games I made in Visual Basic.

I went through the process of building a .jar file as an Artifact in Intellij IDEA, and eventually, one was produced. When I tried to run the file however, it started to open but then crashed. I couldn't figure out why even after rummaging through my Console looking for errors to no avail (I'm using a Mac,) and after attempting to open the jar on a PC I found around the house, I concluded it was an error with the app. I soon found that I hadn't signed the jar, causing a security error, so I went through the process of trying to self-sign. When I tried to do *that*, it worked, but the jar still wouldn't open.

Evidently, there is a underlying issue with my app that needs to be remedied. I have no idea where to start looking, largely because I have tried several times to create new files, including a Hello World application, none of which resulted in a functioning application.

So, [here's the entire project.](https://github.com/Lloyd7113/Crawler/tree/master/src/sample)

If any of you would like to have a look through it and point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it, and credit you on my Game Jolt page. This has been giving me headaches for far too long, and I'm about to give up and learn a new bloody language. Please help, it's always appreciated.

Sincerely, a 15-year-old Java-lover who just wants to produce a damn dungeon crawler, fgs.

UPDATE: As per @AndreyAkhmetov's advice, I removed the Class-Path from my manifest file. Unfortunately however, I still don't get anything opening when trying to launch the application. Hope this helps, everyone. Thanks for the feedback so far!

Comment: Please don't like to code in your question.  LIkely you are having an issue with your build - can you post the code in the question above to your build script?  What errors are you getting when you try to run the code?

Comment: Currently on mobile so can't really test, but the Class-Path referencing an absolute directory on your machine looks a bit fishy. Could you remove it from the Manifest.MF file, attempt to build the jar, and report back? Also, please give some information on what steps you are taking to actually build the JAR, including any commands, IDEs, or other build tools you are using.

Comment: I've cloned your repo and it does not run. Please include all resources it needs to run like images.

Comment: @elbraulio My bad, I added the images in there. It should run in your IDE now.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov Thanks, I will try this, and post any updates at the bottom of the question.

Comment: From the code you've linked it looks like you have _many_ `catch` blocks that simply swallow the exception. One of these could be the source of the problem but we can't know because you don't, at the very least, log the exceptions.

Comment: What Slaw said.  **Never** write an empty catch block.  At the very least, call `e.printStackTrace()`.  Realistically, though, you should just exit.  You don’t want to try to keep running if you can’t load an image, do you?

Comment: One of the many problems that you load the images from the filesystem. That means that to run your program you need an "Images" folder with the images next to the jar file. It would be better to read them as resources (using for example `new Image("Images/dead.png")`) and place the Images folder into the src folder

Answer (score 0):

I have made a [pull request](https://github.com/Lloyd7113/Crawler/pull/2) to fix your game ;).

your problem is how to load resources. You can use maven to organize your project and resources. It helps to make your project platform independent and easy to share.
you should use this structure:

```
Crawler /
    src /
        main/
           java/
           resources/
               Images/ 
pom.xml
```

The **pom.xml** is a configuration file and all your resources like Images are in the **resources folder**. Then you can load it using this:

```
InputStream loadimg = Main.class
            .getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("Images/chest.png");
chest.setImage(new Image(loadimg));
```

also you should change the directories where you load saved files, from this `c\\...` to this `./saved.txt`. Then the jar can be executed from anywhere.

To create an artifact you can do

```
$ mvn package
```

or if you are using Intellij, in the side bar click on Maven then on lifecycle and package.
That will create a target folder with the jar inside, you can execute it by clicking on it or with this command to see the console errors.

```
java -jar Crawler.jar
```

Try to split your components from your Main class, it is too large and difficult to read and understand.
Nice game, good luck!